# Postgres indexing string to optimise for LIKE/iLIKE

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I am hoping to optimise certain queries that will look abit like

```
SELECT id, title, ... 
FROM things
WHERE tenant_id = 1
AND title LIKE '%anything%'
```

I attempted to add a GIN index

```
CREATE INDEX gin_title ON things USING gin(to_tsvector('english', title));
```

However, it seems like the index is not used?

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT * FROM things
WHERE title LIKE 'test%';

Seq Scan on uris  (cost=0.00..2207.50 rows=2 width=193) (actual time=1.375..5.133 rows=4 loops=1)
  Filter: ((title)::text ~~ 'test%'::text)                                                       
  Rows Removed by Filter: 53796                                                                  
Planning Time: 0.287 ms                                                                          
Execution Time: 5.158 ms
```

Is there a need to specify a language? Cos I dont need any form of tokenization, I mainly just want to do things like case insensitive substring, prefix and suffix match mainly.

Also, thinking ahead, since typically I need to query by other fields too, example the "tenant_id" how might I include that into the index but not as part of the GIN index perhaps? Cos I think that's more expensive?